# pandas get dummies on comma delimited column creating duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series like so:

```
0 mcdonalds, popeyes
1 wendys
2 popeyes
3 mcdonalds
4 mcdonalds
```

I want to convert to dummy variables where my expected output is like so:

```
popeyes wendys mcdonalds
1       0      1
0       1      0
1       0      0
0       0      1
0       0      1
```

however when i use the following code:

```
t.str.get_dummies(sep = ',')

popeyes wendys mcdonalds popeyes
1       0      1         0
0       1      0         0 
0       0      0         1
0       0      1         0
0       0      1         0
```

why does it split out popeyes in two columns, how do i fix this?

Comment: Because there is a space after the comma in your first line. So one column is probably `' popeyes'` and the other one is just `'popeyes'`

Comment: Try `sep = ', '` (note the space after the comma)

Comment: Oh wow. Hacky. I like it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To convert your series into dummy variables, where each unique value becomes a separate column, you can use the get_dummies() function from the pandas library. However, before applying get_dummies(), make sure to preprocess your series by properly splitting the values. Here's an example code snippet that should help:

```
import pandas as pd

# Assume your series is named "series"
dummy_df = series.str.get_dummies(sep=', ')

# Print the resulting dummy variables
print(dummy_df)
```

By running this code, you should get an output dataframe where each unique value in your series is represented as a separate column, filled with ones and zeros. This technique can be useful for encoding categorical variables into a format suitable for machine learning models or further analysis.

Comment: Is there a way to drop a level like there is in pd.get_dummies()?

Comment: yes , u can do this ```dummy_df = dummy_df.droplevel(0, axis=1)```